# Como decompor uma Série temporal usando uma frequência de 6 meses?

Tags: r

Tenho uma amostra de dados com o período de um ano. Eu gero a série temporal sem problemas com a `frequency = 12`, porém quando vou usar o `decompose` ele mostra a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
Error in decompose(teste_compras) : 
  série temporal não tem período, ou tem menos de 2
```

Pelo que eu entendi minha série temporal tem uma frequência de 12 meses, mas eu preciso de uma amostra com pelo menos 2 anos para ter 2 períodos. Porém, minha amostra tem apenas 12 meses e não possui mais dados anteriores.

O que eu gostaria de saber, se é possível gerar uma série temporal com frequência de 6 meses para pode gerar dois períodos de 6 meses e assim poder decompor a série. É possível?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso pode ser feito computacionalmente, mas não faz sentido matematicamente.

Imagine que tu tenha as temperaturas médias mensais de Porto Alegre, uma cidade com verão e inverno bem definidos. Mas tu tem apenas um ano de observações (ou seja, n=12). Sendo dados de temperatura, faz sentido imaginar que a sazonalidade destes dados é anual. Afinal, os janeiros na cidade tendem a serem quentes, enquanto os julhos tendem a serem frios.

Sazonalidade significa que o comportamento das observações tendem a se repetir depois de um período fixo de tempo. Não faz sentido, em termos de modelagem, dividir uma série como esta em dois períodos de seis meses. Afinal, uma sazonalidade de seis meses implicaria que o comportamento em janeiro e julho seriam similares; em fevereiro e agosto também; em março e setembro e assim por diante. E, ao menos para uma série de temperaturas, sabemos que o comportamento destes pares de meses são opostos: a temperatura aumenta de janeiro a fevereiro, mas baixa de julho a agosto.

O teu problema não tem solução respaldada na teoria de séries temporais incluindo sazonalidade no período. Ou mais dados devem ser coletados (e, mesmo assim, são *bem mais dados*: se sugerem de 50 a 100 observações para ajustar um modelo de séries temporais), ou desista da sazonalidade. Afinal, com 12 observações, uma sazonalidade de período 12 sequer vai ser detectada pela função de autocorrelação.

Comment: Entendi. Muito obrigado pela resposta.